# Reading file into a struct (C++)

Tags: c++, file, struct, binary

I'm trying to read data from a binary file and put it into a struct.
The first few bytes of `data.bin` are:

```
03 56 04 FF FF FF ...
```

And my implementation is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    struct header {
        unsigned char type;
        unsigned short size;
    } fileHeader;

    std::ifstream file ("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
    file.read ((char*) &fileHeader, sizeof header);

    std::cout << "type: " << (int)fileHeader.type;
    std::cout << ", size: " << fileHeader.size << std::endl;

}
```

The output I was expecting is `type: 3, size: 1110`, but for some reason it's `type: 3, size: 65284`, so basically the second byte in the file is skipped. What's happening here?

Comment: What is `sizeof(header)`? I'm willing to bet it's `4`...

Comment: Heh, yeah. I should've checked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the behavior is implementation-defined. What actually happens in your case probably is, there is a padding of 1 byte, after `type` member of the struct, then after that follows the second member `size`. I based this argument after seeing the output.

Here is your input bytes:

```
03 56 04 FF FF FF
```

the first byte `03` goes to the first byte of the struct, which is `type`, and you see this `3` as output. Then next byte `56` goes to the second byte which is the padding hence ignored, then the next two bytes `04 FF` goes to the next two bytes of the struct which is `size` (which is of size `2` bytes). On little-endian machine, `04 FF` is interpreted as `0xFF04` which is nothing but `66284` which you get as output.

And you need basically a compact struct so as to squeeze the padding. Use `#pragma` pack. But such a struct would be slow compared to the normal struct. A better option is to fill the struct manually as:

```
char bytes[3];
std::ifstream file ("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
file.read (bytes, sizeof bytes); //read first 3 bytes

//then manually fill the header
fileHeader.type = bytes[0];
fileHeader.size = ((unsigned short) bytes[2] << 8) | bytes[1];
```

Another way to write the last line is this:

```
fileHeader.size = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(bytes+1);
```

But this is implementation-defined, as it depends on the endian-ness of the machine. On little-endian machine, it most likely would work.

A friendly approach would be this (implementation-defined):

```
std::ifstream file ("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
file.read (&fileHeader.type, sizeof fileHeader.type);
file.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fileHeader.size), sizeof fileHeader.size);
```

But again, the last line depends on the endian-ness of the machine.

Comment: The padding would be in the struct, not the file.  Try the pragma pack: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks again for this very detailed explanation.
I now fill each member of the struct by itself as you recommended. That seems to work best.

Comment: lol, told the OP to do stuff that's not really the best approach,  read my answer and edited yours ;) kudos, at least he won't mess with pragmas anymore

Comment: @Castilho: What is "lol"? Also, what is wrong with what approach? I've mentioned several approach, so be specific. As for your approach, will that work on big-endian machine?

Comment: the pragma packing? everything. the other were inserted later, that's why the lol =) And if your are reading binary data, you have to be aware of the endianness of your machine, no silver bullet for that. Writing everything individually is better even in this sense, as you can swap the bytes on the method that reads the file. With pragma packing you have to swap the bytes later, and then you'll have to allocate temporary vars, it's just hell. But for now I'm just happy that such a garbage approach as pragma packing won't be tagged as the right answer anymore.

Comment: http://solidsmoke.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/woes-of-structure-packing-pragma-pack.html see? at least Krister Andersson popped the default back

Comment: @Castilho: You're saying pragma packing as if I said it "best approach". Where did I say it is "best approach"? Also, what *"swap the bytes later"* and *"allocate temporary vars"* are you talking about?  By the way, your *"lol"* is cute and childish. ;-)

Comment: @Castilho: Again, you're saying *"at least Krister Andersson popped the default back"* as if I said "don't do that". Really?

Comment: Hey, do not think it's personal. I just thought that it was problematic if the answer tagged as right only told about pragma packing. Now you edited it, kudos. And I disagree on 'lol', everybody has the right to laugh sometimes :)

Comment: Nothing personal. I'm just pointing out the problem with your so-called "best approach", without even exercising *"the right to laugh"*... Also, by the time, you commented on my answer with your cute "lol", I had mentioned many approaches in my answer; it didn't only contain pragma, as you seem to think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it could be struct padding. In order to make structs work fast on modern architectures, some compilers will put padding in there to keep them aligned on 4 or 8 byte boundaries.

You can override this with a pragma or a compiler setting. eg. Visual studio its [/Zp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If this was happening then you'd see the value 56 in the first char, then it'd read the next n bytes in to the padding, and then read the next 2 into the short. If the 2nd byte was lost as padding, then the next 2 bytes are being read into the short. And as the short now contains the data '04 FF', this (in little endian) equates to 0xff04 which is 65284.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers pad structs to bytes that are multiple of 2 or 4 to make the access to them easier to implement in machine code. I would not use #pragma pack unless it was really necessary, and that usually only apply when you are working at really low level (like firmware level).
[Wikipedia article on that.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

That happens because microprocessors have specific operantions to access memory on addresses that are multiple of four or two, and that makes the source code easier to make, it uses memory more efficiently, and sometimes the code is a little bit faster. There are ways to stop that behavior, of course like the pragma pack directive, but they are compile dependent. But to override the compiler defaults is usually a bad idea, the compiler guys had a very good reason to make it behave that way.

A better solution, to me, would be to solve that with pure C, which is very, very simple, and would follow a good programming practice, namely: never rely on what the compiler is doing with your data at low level.

I know that just doing #pragma pack(1) is sexy, simple, and gives us all a sense that we are dealing and understanding directly what's happening on the guts of the computer, and that turns every real programmer on, but the best solution is always the one that is implemented with the language you're using. It's easier to understand and therefore easier to maintain; it's default behavior, so it should work everywhere, and, in this specific case, the C solution is really simple and straightfoward: just read your struct attribute by attribute, like this:

```
void readStruct(header &h, std::ifstream file)
{
    file.read((char*) &h.type, sizeof(char));
    file.read((char *) &h.size, sizeof(short));
}
```

(this will work if you define the struct globally, of course)

Even better, as you are working with C++, would be to define a member method to do that reading for you, and later just call `myObject.readData(file)`. Can you see the beauty and the simplicity?

Easier to read, to maintain, to compile, leads to faster and optimized code, it's default.

I usually don't like to mess with #pragma directives unless I am pretty certain about what I'm doing. The implications can be suprising.

Comment: If the program that produced the file ran on a big-endian machine, yes. If you have to write code to work with a little-endian file on a big-endian machine, you'll have to explicitly handle that.

Comment: which means it will not work everywhere, contrary to your claim *"so it should work everywhere"*, and certainly not the best approach. I've provided several approaches and also mentioned the issues with each one, if any.

Comment: Hey man, you should handle your anger. Everything must be read with some common sense in mind. There's no code that works everywhere. You have to be aware of the limitations of what you're doing. As pointed out, if the file writer and the reader are from the same machine, it will work. If not, you'll have to handle that problems individually. But enough of that, these are comments, I tried to help, and you took it personally. I'm sorry if I made you angry, now enjoy your saturday.

Comment: Exactly. 1) *"Everything must be read with some common sense in mind. There's no code that works everywhere"*, as you said beautifully. 2) I'm no angry. You just told me to read your answer, and I did, and then I found that it has problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `#pragma pack` compiler directive to override the padding issue:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct header {
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned short size;
} fileHeader;
#pragma pack(pop)
```