# How can i skip over structures when writing in a binary file [c++]

Tags: c++, file, binary, structure, ofstream

I have a structure :

```
struct Ticket
{
    bool IsReserved; // Is the seat resereved (true)
    time_t SoldOn; //When has the ticket been bought
    double Price; // Price of the ticket
    Ticket() {  IsReserved = 0; Price = 0; SoldOn = 0; }
};
```

I have already saved it as many times as I needed in a binary file and I read it correctly.
My question is when how can I modify only 1 structure when the user wants to buy a ticket. For example when he wants to buy the 5th seat he should go to the 5th structure and change only that data. Here is how I try to do it.

```
std::cout<<"\nPlease enter how many tickets would you like to purchase : \n";
do
{   
    if(number<0 || number > freeSeats)
        std::cerr<<"Invalid input.try again: \n";
    std::cin>>number;

}while(number<0 || number > freeSeats);

int *t = new int[number];

for(int i = 0; i<number; i++)
{
    int seat = 0;

    do
    {

        std::cout<<"Please enter seat "<<i<<" : ";
        std::cin>>seat;

        file.clear();
        file.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
        for(int i =1; i <= seat; i++)
        {
            serializeTickets(file,ticket);
        }
        if(ticket.IsReserved == 1)
            std::cout<<"The ticket has already been reserved\n";
    }while(ticket.IsReserved == 1);

    t[i] = seat;
}

file.close();

schedule.serializeTargetLine(choice);
std::ofstream myFile(ticketsFileName,std::ios::binary || std::ios::out);

for(int i = 0; i<number; i++)
{
    time_t timer(0);
    std::time(&timer);

    myFile.seekp(+(t[i] - 1)*sizeof(Ticket),std::ios::beg);

    ticket.IsReserved=1;
    ticket.Price = atof(schedule.getPrice().c_str());
    ticket.SoldOn = timer;

    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&ticket),sizeof(Ticket));
}

delete[] t;
myFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're compiling with GCC, I encourage you to add -Wall to your compiler flags to get the maximum compiler assistance.

The problem appears to be that you are not opening the file for writing:

```
std::ofstream myFile(ticketsFileName,std::ios::binary || std::ios::out);
```

when you probably mean't

```
std::ios::binary | std::ios::out
```

or
    (std::ios::binary | std::ios::out)

If you turn on full compiler warnings, it would tell you that you have a boolean operation where you probably mean't to have a logical.

and, yes, you probably [should use pragma pack around the structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16644047/257645). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935(v=vs.80).aspx and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852860/257645

Note, unless you are targetting older compilers, you can do this as:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct ... {
    ...
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

(Short version: This tells the compiler to use an in-memory representation of the structure that may be less run-time performant but will create a less environment-dependent footprint for storage like this)

Comment: /W4 for MSVC. /WX (or -Werror for GCC) will turn warnings into errors if you want to give them a little more urgency.

Comment: can i added anywhere.In my case the struct is in a class to so only 1 part of my programm can access it.can i use the pragma there or should i move the structure ?

Comment: It needs to be around the outside of the definition of the data you plan to write. You could declare the data elements - that you plan to write to disk - in a struct `struct TicketData { ... }` wrapped with the pack pragmas, then inherit that to Ticket, `class Ticket : protected TicketData`, which does not need to be pragma packed.

When you write the structure, in Ticket::write() do `TicketData* data = dynamic_cast<TicketData*>(this);` and `fwrite(static_cast<char*>(data), sizeof(*data));`

Answer (score 0):

When writing the file, I would probably use the following before writing struct data to a file.

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

After that, it's just a matter of using `sizeof(ticket) * seat` as the seek offset from the beginning of the file.

```
file.seekg((sizeof(ticket) * seat), std::ios::beg);
```

Comment: where should i add the #pragma ?

Comment: Anywhere between your #include statements and before the first line of executable code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a job for a real database, which will have all these fiddly details already figured out for you (but which will of course have other fiddly details).

That said, your code looks at first glance like it should work (aside from the | vs || issue pointed out by kfsone). If you'll allow me to nitpick a bit:

- `std::vector` should be preferred over array-new, as it encapsulates the most error-prone pieces.
- Blitting the `Ticket` struct directly to/from a fiie is technically a violation of the Standard, since it has a constructor.
- You might want to consider using a `std::fstream` opened for both reading and writing instead of opening the same file twice.
- Many things can go wrong while reading and writing files. Your code should handle those things gracefully. For instance,

  - read() and write() are allowed to read/write fewer bytes than you specify
  - if a seek goes past the end of the file, it may fail.

Comment: i tried to open it with fstream but is started crashing.I have no idea why.And since its a class project i'm only alowed to use files,no db's.